# pdoexception not outputting error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname;charset=utf8', 'username', 'password');
    try
    {
        //Prepare and execute an insert into DB         
        $st = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO users(login,pass,email,county) VALUES(:username,:password,:email,:county)");        
        $st->execute(array(':username' => $_POST['username'], ':password' => $_POST['password1'], ':email' => $_POST['email'], ':county' => $_POST['county']));
        echo 'Success';
    }
    catch (PDOException $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
```

Hi, I am not completely familiar with pdo but I thought I would add a few error exceptions, except I won't actually display the error normally as I don't want everyone to know my schema. In this case I changed my working code to a non working code by changing "...,county)" to "....,count)" which obviously did not insert into the database at all but still shown "Success" and no error.

Please help :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set PDO error mode to throw exception.

```
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Comment: Thanks, but where should I put that?